# Как понять, что числа перестали поступать на ввод?

Tags: python, структуры-данных, ввод

Вот задача: Считывание при стандартном вводе заранее неизвестного количества целых чисел (типа longint или long), каждое число находится в отдельной строке. Весь список входных данных преобразуется в стандартный вывод два раза подряд.Надо сделать через классы и методы. Класс я написал, но не могу сделать правильный ввод, который перестанет работать, когда числа перестанут поступать. Видел советы по sys.stdin.read() и sys.stdin.readline, но не могу понять, как с ними работать.

Comment: ничего не понятно. В питоне нет longint и long. Что означает " преобразуется в стандартный вывод два раза подряд"? Понять что на ввод перестали поступать числа очень просто - если введена пустая строка, то перестали.

Comment: Вводятся числа, каждое на новой строке. Ими нужно заполнить связный список и потом вывести его два раза подряд. Я понимаю, что это элементарно, нужно сделать какой-то while, но не могу понять, какое условие писать.

Comment: `while True: data = input(); if not data: break; ...`

Comment: Хорошо, вроде работает, спасибо)

Comment: заполнение списка и его вывод не имеют отношения к определнию того, прекратился ли ввод данных, поэтому в вопросе это упоминать совершенно не нужно